# How to horizontally center an item in Material UI Grid item?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How do I center elements inside a Material UI `Grid` item? Here is a snippet from my React application:

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    // Unrelated stuff here
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    // How do I centre these items?
    <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit">
      <EditIcon/>
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit">
      <CheckBoxIcon/>
    </IconButton>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    // Unrelated stuff here
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I've tried applying `alignContent`, `justify`, `alignItems` (to the parent `<Grid item>`) with no success.

I thought this would be quite simple, but I've failed to find any information on centering items inside of grid items.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Two seconds later... I solved this through some simple CSS:

```
<Grid item xs={4} style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
</Grid>
```

If there is another approach that is somehow more "correct", please feel free to post another answer.

Comment: this is perfectly correct, since the elements are inline (or inline-block) then centring is done by text-align

Comment: If you want to center a button in a item Grid, this is the way

Answer (score 30):

```
 <Grid container  className = {classes.root} align = "center" justify = "center" alignItems = "center"  >
            <CssBaseline/>
            <Grid item xs = {false} sm = {4} md = {6}>

            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs = {12} sm = {4} md = {6}>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>`enter code here`
```

Comment: Thanks, `align="center"` property worked for me. Why this isn't on docs ? https://material-ui.com/api/grid/

Comment: `align="center"` did the job. The docs can be so bad for material-ui...

Comment: align="center" worked for me as well. Thanks

Comment: The align property isn't a Material UI property. It's just HTML. It simply tacks on `align="center"` to the output HTML. The solution of `<Grid container item justify="center">` is the correct idiomatic approach for Material UI.

Answer (score 25):

This is the correct way:

```
<Grid container item xs={4} justify="center">
```

> if container property is set to true the component will have the flex
>   container behavior.

[Grid API](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/)

Comment: This (applying to container) does not work with typography inside Grid item. But `<Grid item style={{textAlign: "center"}}>` works.

Answer (score 7):

In **MUI v5**, according the the [migration guide](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#grid), The `justify` prop of `Grid` is renamed to `justifyContent` to align with the CSS property name:

```
<Grid container justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
```

Comment: Just to add to this: what I found confusing when centering content inside of <Grid item>'s was that we have to apply the `container` prop as well to give the `item` flex container behaviour in order to make `justifyContent` work. Ie. `<Grid container><Grid container item justifyContent="center"><MyItem /></Grid></Grid>`

Comment: mui5 - This (applying to container) does not work with typography inside Grid item. But `<Grid item style={{textAlign: "center"}}>` works.