# Does Material UI Grid Item require defined breakpoints on positional properties ? (textAlign / text-align in my case)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

extension to this question: [How to horizontally center an item in Material UI grid item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357717/how-to-horizontally-center-an-item-in-material-ui-grid-item)

I've noticed this behavior but I was unable to find corresponding explanation in my look into the Grid documentation for material UI

in essence, I have a button within a grid item that is in a grid container that I am trying to center. It looks like this

```
      <Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={9}>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12} style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
            <Button>Create a Post</Button>
          </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

The code above only runs because I provided the breakpoint of xs={12}, without which it would refuse to center the element.

My question being, is this a requirement that I provide a breakpoint when I attempt to center elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, give your Element inside a grid a **fullWidth**  property, otherwise it is not going to display as you wish.
By default your element is not centered inside of grid, so yes, you need to provide some styles. No need to make a grid inside of another grid. If you fork your code in sandbox, I can help more.

```
<Grid item xs={3}  style={{//center here, using flexbox or something else}}>          
   <Button fullWidth>Create a Post</Button>          
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Tigran,

Thanks for your response,

codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-keller-3bv9h?file=/src/App.js:363-370

I understand that I have to add the styling to get it to center, what I cant figure out is why it would not center if I had omitted xs={12} from the code.

I also note that even without the fullWidth property u had pointed out I could still get it to center (i will investigate fullWidth abit later)

Comment: I am also more curious on the behavior than the actual practical use as you pointed out

Comment: I see what the fullWidth property does, that is helpful thank you. In this case I just need it to center (i.e. with white spaces to left and right)

Comment: I recommend you to install one very useful extension on chrome, called Pesticide. When you toogle it, it shows all your html boxes. How material ui grid works. Inside a container, you put items and define how they should look like. xs={9} means element will take 3/4 th of the screen on mobile view . Usually you always want to have xs={12} so they will be shown one after another. Use both md and xs. Knowing that you can already figure out how it works and what it displays. If you want the element be exactly in the centre of a grid, use display: flex, alignItems: center, justifyContent: center.

Comment: Tigran,

Thanks for the extension recommendation, I will check it out, it sounds helpful!

Comment: Welcome! If your question is resolved, mark it as resolved so other developers can see it too.

Comment: I think the core question still hasn't been resolved yet. Again , I havent quite understood why I had needed to provide that breakpoint. Can't the textAlign work without the xs={12}? 

I am unable to find anything in the documentation that says the breakpoint is required. Even in your answer you had provided 

``` <Grid item xs={3}  style={{//center here, using flexbox or something else}}>       ```

Comment: If you removed the xs={12} from my code sandbox, you should see the behavior I am referring to, that the button does not center

Comment: The text-align property specifies the horizontal alignment of text in an element. Text-align doesn't affect button element's position itself. You better read documentation of css styles, will make more sense :) Text-align is usually used to format text inside of div let's say.

Comment: Let me create an example and send to you okay ? 
You will see it yourself.

Comment: Tigran, If you could that would be helpful.


as I saw from the link that this question arises from , the solution provider did mention that the textAlign method is more of a "hack" than the ideal solution

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-pine-1uyeg?file=/src/App.js 

Here, play around a little bit with this code, change values, check what is happening and why. Here pesticide doesn't work unfortunately, you can copy this code to your local text editor, run and check in your browser.

Comment: Tigran,

This is amazing, thank you for this, this helps in visualization.

Again, I can see that in your examples all of them provided breakpoints, if you removed the breakpoints in the first button (i.e. md={3} xs={12}) and the fullWidth, the button no longer shifts to the center.

This is the behavior that I am trying to figure out if it is being documented anywhere or is a commonly understood thing that I have not come across.. which is why I am asking here.

Comment: the style boilerplate is extremely useful thank you.

Comment: Welcome!
There is a joke about the duck: If something quacks like a duck, walks like a duck and behaves like a duck, then it is a duck. The moral is, If you need to add breakpoints to style as you need, there is no need to understand why it doesn't work if you remove them. If they don't provide anything in the documentation for this case, then it is not needed, don't overwhelm yourself. Just use what you have and what is provided in the documentation.

Comment: Hi Tigran,

Thats fine, i guess i will take it for what it is then!